# What is a formal definition of the following pointwise limit in the component of a matrix $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\|f(h^0)\|^2_2=? $?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, statistics

Given a vector $h^0\in R^n$, let a function $f: R\to R$ that is applied componentwise to vectors. What is a formal definition of the following pointwise limit in the component?

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\|f(h^0)\|^2_2=\lim \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n [f(h_i^0)]^2 \, ?
$$

I try to let $h^0=[h_1^0, h_2^0, \dots, h_n^0]^T$ and if
$$f(h^0)=f([h_1^0, h_2^0, \dots, h_n^0]^T)=[f(h_1^0), f(h_2^0), \dots, f(h_n^0)]^T....$$

Comment: Isn't your question missing some information ? Unless I'm mistaken, for a fixed $h^0$, the quantity $\|f(h^0)\|^2_2$ is constant, which implies that $\frac{1}{n}\|f(h^0)\|^2_2\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: @StratosFair Sorry, $f$ is applied componentwise to vectors

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood. Since $h^0$ is a constant vector, then $f(h^0)$ is a constant vector as well and its $\ell_2$ norm is also a constant, hence the limit is that of a constant divided by $n$ and is zero. Is it what you wanted to prove ? I do not understand your question

Comment: I believe that the limit is not zero. Is that $f(h^0)$ a $R^n$ vector? Then the $\ell_2$ norm of it is a sum of $\sum_{i=1}^n f(h_i^0)^2$, right? So the limit also depends on the numerator?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that, I totally missed the dependency on $n$ ! Then I guess we need some information on $f$ and on how that sequence $h_i^0$ is generated. With no additional information, the quantity you're interested in is the average of arbitrary non-negative numbers, we can't conclude anything about the existence of a limit.

Comment: StratosFair is right, and (to answer the title question) you got the definition correct as far as I can tell. A simple sufficient condition is if $f(h^0_i)^2 \to c$ then your limit is also $c$. This condition is not necessary; a google-able keyword is Cesàro summation

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes, we can assume the limit exists, right?

Comment: No, there are examples where the limit doesn’t, something like sin(log x)